# optimize curve_fit for arbitrary sum of a input function

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, curve-fitting

So I can use scipy curve fit to obtain parameters for my function defined below; it is basically a difference of gaussians.

```
def diff_of_err_func(x, amp=None, pos=None, width=None, c=0):
    '''
    :return:
    '''
    Gx = amp*0.5*sp.special.erf((x + pos)/width) - amp*0.5*sp.special.erf((x - pos)/width) - c

    return Gx
```

To get results, I use:

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(diff_of_err_func, xCoords, yValues)
Gx = diff_of_err_func(xCoords, *popt)
```

What is a smart way to fit an arbitrary sum of the so-defined `diff_of_err_func` function ?, with the number, N, of functions, also part of the optimization ?

I have searched for examples using `optimize.curve_fit` on an arbitrary number of gaussians but I am not sure how to write the call to  `optimize.curve_fit` for this case. Thanks

GT

Comment: Opps, I should say in the opening paragraph ..."difference of err fucntions" ... rather than "difference of gaussians".